# Javascript Regex Pattern for Indian Vehicle number

Tags: javascript

I need a regular expression in Javascript for Indian vehicle NUMBER.

Expression should match following patterns.

1. **GL/48/ED/1220**
2. **MH/24/ L/3654**

I have tried following  pattern but didn't work.

```
 str = "MH/14/AA/2000";                                                             
 var pattern = /[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]/[0-9][0-9]/[A-Za-z ][a-z]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/;
 var result = str.match(pattern);                    
 console.log(result);
```

result gives null.

Anyone have solution for it?

Comment: You have an unescaped `/` after `[0-9]/`

Comment: /[A-Z]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/ ?[A-Z]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/                  - try e.g. here: https://regex101.com

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. !

Comment: My suggestion when you work with regex is to use a tool such as, https://regexr.com/ to validate. It will give you hints, as missing \ for escaping and "i" flag for case insensitivity, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three problems

- **Un-escaped `/`**

/ will end your regular expression, so you need to escape those which are in the middle of it

```
 var pattern = /[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[A-Za-z ][a-z]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/;
```

- **typo** - pattern instead of `patt1`

i.e.

```
 var result = str.match(pattern);
```

- **case-sensitive matching**

Either use `[A-Z]` with `i` to ignore case-sensitive matching or just use `[A-Z]` in all of them

**Finally**

```
 str = "MH/14/AA/2000";                                                             
 var pattern = /[A-Z][A-Z]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[A-Z][A-Z]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/i;
 var result = str.match(pattern);                    
 console.log(result);
```

*Less verbose version*

```
 str = "MH/14/AA/2000";                                                             
 var pattern = /[A-Z]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[A-Z]{2}\/\d{4}$/i;
 var result = str.match(pattern);                    
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var pattern = /[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]/[0-9][0-9]/[A-Za-z ][A-Za-z]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/;`

The diff to your expression is:
The slashes / need to be escaped with backslash \, the second part of letters missed the uppercase A-Z